# What is the maximum amount of light through a fiber

Tags: visible-light

I was wandering what the maximum amount (not the bandwidth, but the amount of photons) of light through a fiber would be.

Comment: The gist is that transmission of light through a fiber isn't perfect. Some of the energy of the beam will be converted to heat. So the limit is dependent on how much heat the fiber can withstand.

Comment: I thought of that, but I wandered if there wass some sort of theoretical maximum of photons in a certain space. Maybe I should have asked that. But thanx MaxW

Comment: There are nonlinear optical effects that is bad for communication. This becomes a problem long before the fiber becomes too hot.